# Replacing all non-zero elements with a number in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to replace all non-zero elements of the array `X` with `10`. Is there a one-step way to do so? I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
X=np.array([[10.                 ,  0.6382821834929432 ,  0.5928417218382795 ,
        0.5542698411479658 ,  0.                 ,  0.6677634679746701 ,
        0.8578897621707481 ,  0.                 ,  0.6544597670890333 ,
        0.32706383813570833,  0.                 ,  0.8966468940380192 ]])
```

The expected output is

```
X=array([[10.,  10. ,  10. ,
        10. ,  0.,  10.,
        10. ,  0.,  10.,
        10.,  0.,  10. ]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
X2 = np.where(X!=0, 10, 0)
```

Or, for in place modification:

```
X[X!=0] = 10
```

For fun, a variant using equivalence of True/False and 1/0:

```
X2 = (X!=0)*10
```

Output:

```
array([[10, 10, 10, 10,  0, 10, 10,  0, 10, 10,  0, 10]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using [numpy.putmask](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.putmask.html?highlight=putmask)

Here is an example for your solution

```
import numpy as np

X=np.array([[10.                 ,  0.6382821834929432 ,  0.5928417218382795 ,
        0.5542698411479658 ,  0.                 ,  0.6677634679746701 ,
        0.8578897621707481 ,  0.                 ,  0.6544597670890333 ,
        0.32706383813570833,  0.                 ,  0.8966468940380192 ]])

np.putmask(X, X != 0, 10)
```

Comment: Interesting alternative (+1), however not really needed here. `putmask` makes sense when the replacing value is not a scalar (and not the size of the mask).

Answer (score 1):

```
X[X !=0]=10.
```

this will works for you